# Replacing digits immediately after a saved pattern

Tags: regex, grep, textwrangler

Searched pattern looks like `text9`

I search for `(text)9`

I want to replace with `\15` so that I would get `text5` but instead it's just giving me `text`.

Any other character works except for digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the PCRE-style back-references do not work.

So, you have to use `\015` to replace with the text captured with the first capturing group (`\01`) and `5`.

Since there cannot be more than 99 capturing groups, and both the digits after `\` are treated as back-reference group number, `\01` is interpreted as the reference to the first group, and the rest are literal digits.

Comment: Curiously neither of those are working. I'm getting ${1}5 or \{1}5 when I try those. Could there be some obscure option I'm not ticking? Does the file type affect anything? BTW thanks for showing me regex101!

Comment: \015 did it, but the second string didn't

Comment: Excellent! I was despairing after trying \{1}5 in a similar problem and getting nowhere. I think sed uses something like that in cases like this, and it came up in some searches. I hate that I didn't think of a leading zero, but I don't think I knew that there was an explicit limit of 2 digits. The syntax coloring in BBEdit immediately showed me that it was working.

Answer (score 2):

The replacement term `\15` is being interpreted as "group 15" - you must escape the "5":

Try replacing with `\1\\5`, or if that doesn't work (I don't have textwrangler handy) use a look behind:

```
Search: (?<=text)9
Replace: 5
```

The look behind doesn't consume input, so only the "9" is matched.

Comment: I expected that there was some method of escaping that I didn't know, unfortunately the double slash wasn't it. The look behind works, though. Thanks for helping me broaden my grepping!